# Limit on weapons used during combat

Tags: eldritch-horror

Is there any sort of limit to the number of weapons or items you can use during combat?

In Arkham Horror, the hand icons restricted the number of weapons/spells/items that you could use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/39/c1/39c182c1-6b0d-46c4-b5eb-dd6886b4c798/eh01_reference_guide1.pdf) (page 12):

> **Q. Can I use multiple weapons during combat?**
>
> A. Yes, but you can only apply the highest bonus to a test. However, 
>   you may use any other effects, from your other weapons. For example, 
>   if you have a Bull Whip Asset and a .45 Automatic Asset, you may 
>   apply the +3 bonus from the .45 to your {combat check} instead of the +1 bonus from the whip, and you may still reroll one die by using the whip’s 
>   other effect.

Comment: To expand on this, you can only apply a single bonus from any one effect, whether it be from a weapon, an ally, or a spell (e.g. Wither). You can still use all non-bonus-stat effects.

Comment: Some more information in this later question too - http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/30013/spells-and-items-during-combat regarding spells.